# Twitter bootstrap top menu is not displaying as strip

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, menu

I just started using twitter bootstrap. Trying each example in their site. However I couldn't succeed in most cases. For instance, the top navigation bar. I just copied into a html file. Changed some reference paths for css, js. When browsed in IE8/Chrome, it shows a weird result.

=== source copied from: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png">


<title>Fixed Top Navbar Example for Bootstrap</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="Scripts/navbar-fixed-top.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../docs-assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Navbar example</h1>
    <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
    <p>To see the difference between static and fixed top navbars, just scroll.</p>
    <p>
      <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

===

> Note: There is a head closing tag body open tag that I couldn't insert
>   (here) right before fixed nav bar

the outcome on my browser:

[image: Nav bar in browser]

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not in the HTML
Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palapas/52VtD/763/)

Copy the js and css from this example and it will work
or include this 2 libs

```
//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css
//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js
```